# Choice of statistical testing - under five mortality rate

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, generalized-linear-model, inference, beta-regression

I am not sure if this question or similar one has been asked before but I have checked and to the best of my knowledge couldn't find a suitable answer.

Here is my confusion:

I have a dataset with under-five mortality rate (U5MR) as the response variable and other bunch of covariates.  In reality the U5MR can take a minimum value of 0 and a maximum value of 1000.

But from the results of my EDA I observed that the density plot of the U5MRs shows a nice normal curve and I tested for normality as well. My struggles are as follows:

A. Can I fit a normal regression model given that the result of the EDA suggest that the data follows a normal distribution?

B. If not, should I choose a model based on the data generating process ( rate )? In this case, I am not sure if beta regression will work given that beta regression has a support (0,1) and the data generating process of my data as a support of (0,1000). Which other distribution can I consider?

Comment: If it is the estimated deaths per 1000 births, then you can transform it to lie within $(0,1)$ by converting it to the estimated probability of death (divide it by 1000). The assumption for linear regression is that the errors are normally distributed. That means for each Y value, the distribution of Y given the covariates is approximately normal and the variance should be about the same for all of them. If each of the estimates are based on a large sample size, then the residuals should be approximately normal. Non-constant variance may be handled using weighted regression.

Comment: @ John L. Thanks a lot. I can go ahead a fit a regression as long as I can show that the assumptions are met?